# How to control the width of a fixed div using `max-width`, % and translate?

Tags: css

I cannot find a way to control the width of a fixed div as I want, when using `max-width` together with a percentage.

Whilst reducing the `max-width` percentage decreases the div's width, its width with `max-width` set at 100% (or higher) is a maximum of 50% of the available screen width.  How can I increase it using CSS?

**CSS**

```
.footnote {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  padding: 2em 1em;
}
.footnote:target {
  display: block;
  max-width: 120%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <h1>ipsum</h1>
  <p>ipsum <a href="#note">note</a></p>
  <div ID="note" class="footnote">
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want the min-width to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *`specify a min-width along with max-width`*. Just using max-width on its own doesn't do anything unless the text tries to overflow that value.
You can set the **min-width** to a `px,em,rem,%,vw` whatever suits your needs.

```css
.footnote {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  padding: 2em 1em;
}

.footnote:target {
background:red;
  display: block;
  min-width:60%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>ipsum</h1>
  <p>ipsum <a href="#note">note</a></p>
  <div ID="note" class="footnote">
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: LoL  thanks Highdef!!  I'd never have thought of that.  The max-width WAS able to reduce the width but couldn't get the width past 50%.  Can you explain why the min-width has "corrected that behaviour?
Seems I ONLY need min-width to control the max-width ...?

Comment: @talvi No problem :) Make sure to accept the answer or rate it. And as for the behaviour, consider this scenario. Suppose your container contains some text and you havn't defined its width, it takes whatever area it occupies by default. If you set a max-width, it just limits the container from growing "beyond" that width, it doesn't set a minimum width but acts as a constraint. And that's why we need a min-width, which limits the container to not shrink "below" that value.

Comment: :)  That's pretty much what I understood, but it didn't work that way.  
The container (the div right?) does contain text and I haven't defined its width (OTHER THAN by using the max-width "command").  I want the div to be 75% of the screen width.  
What seems wierd is I've found I can delete the max-width and just use the min-width on its own to achieve this, which seems bass ackwards.

Comment: @talvi It isn't because the width of any container or element for that matter grows. Even if you set the width to 75% it will work without the use of min-width or max-width. We use those two when we need it to switch sizes either absolute or relative. If we want the container to always remain at 75% of the viewport, just use width:75%;

Comment: D'oh! True.
What I actually want here is for the `div class="note"` to be a percentage of the size of the `div class="main"` - BUT also I want the `div class="note"` to be fixed!

Comment: @talvi Yeah width:value%; will do that exactly on footnote or whatever class it is.